# How to trigger new mail Gigya API - Already registered user try to register

Tags: javascript, gigya

When the user tries to register Need to trigger a mail if the email is already registered.

```
 raasOnBeforeSubmit: function (event) {
        // Before Submit - Do Something
        //var event = true;
        console.log(event.eventName);
        console.log(event.form);
        if (event.form == "gigya-register-form" ){
            console.log('Email from formModel ' + event.formData.email);
              var isAvailable = true;
             var email = event.formData.email;
             gigya.accounts.isAvailableLoginID({
                        loginID: email,
                        callback: function(response) {
                            if (response.isAvailable == true) {
                                console.log("Email is new");
                            } else { 
                                isAvailable = false;
                                **console.log("Email already available");
                             //Here wants to trigger a email to the registered user.**
----------------------
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
             });
             
             
        }
        
            return false;
        
        
    },
```

When submit the registration form Im getting the console If the email is already available.

Here I need to send a mail to the registered email ID to inform to reset the password.

In SAP application.

Comment: an additional email verification email, or just a random email of some other kind?

Comment: @Levi  to the user entered email.

Comment: Hi. If that is the flow you want, you would use https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.resetPassword+JS to send a reset password email. However, why not let the screen-sets do it, they handle this automatically. If a user tries to register with an existing loginID, the screen will tell them the email already exists, the isAvailableLoginId is part of the screen-set behavior. so they will know when they type it if they already exist or not and there is a link in the screen for resetting password they can click if they don't know what they used previously.

Comment: [ran out of room in last comment]. Additionally, the onBeforeSubmit happens when the user presses the submit button, before the screen sends the data, which they will not be able to do as long as the email they entered is flagged as already exists, so I am not sure this code will ever run if they enter an email that already exists.